# Angular schematics for library: building schematics gives error in angular 10

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library, angular-schematics

As per Angular doc on schematics for library https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries I tried running script to build schematics with `npm run build` https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries#building-your-schematics

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p tsconfig.schematics.json",
    "copy:schemas": "cp --parents schematics/*/schema.json ../../dist/my-lib/",
    "copy:files": "cp --parents -p schematics/*/files/** ../../dist/my-lib/",
    "copy:collection": "cp schematics/collection.json ../../dist/my-lib/schematics/collection.json",
    "postbuild": "npm run copy:schemas && npm run copy:files && npm run copy:collection"
  }
```

It logs below error

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! library-name build: `../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p tsconfig.schematics.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the library-name build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-25T11_20_07_784Z-debug.log
```

It is giving error while executing `../../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p tsconfig.schematics.json`

P.S. I'm using Angular-10 to create library. Thanks.

Comment: At the root level **package.json** file, add this under **scripts** section - **"alternate": "./projects/my-lib && tsc -p tsconfig.schematics.json"**. After that, try this command in console from root of the project **npm run alternate**.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh This way also doesn't work. Even I tried with only `tsc -p tsconfig.schematics.json` it logs `node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.d.ts:7066:111 - error TS1005: ',' expected.` at multiple lines.